# Count specific condition in 2d-array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D Array, count the number data at column 3 where it is the same.

For example,

```
 String[][] array = {
                    { "red", "value1", "alpha"  },
                    { "blue", "value2", "alpha"  }, 
                    { "green", "value3", "alpha"  }, 
                    { "black", "value4", "alpha" },
                    { "grey", "value1", "beta"  },
                    { "white", "value2", "beta"  }, 
            };

          int counter=0;
          for(String[] subArray : array)
              for(String string : subArray)
                  if(string.toLowerCase().equals("beta"))
                      counter++;

          System.out.println(counter);
```

The output of the counter for beta = 2 and alpha = 4.

Assuming I don't know what is the exact name of the data in column 3, how I count the conditions? `if(string.toLowerCase().equals(???))`

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It could be something like this using `groupingBy` in java 8:

```
 Arrays.stream(array)
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[2], Collectors.counting()));
```

Result will:

```
{alpha=4, beta=2}
```

B.T.W If you want to ignore case, do it as:

```
Arrays.stream(array)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[2].toLowerCase(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Map<String, int>`

Look for the value of `string.toLowerCase` in the Map and if it is found increment the value of `int` else insert with the value of `1`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, but one way:

1. Create a new multidimensional array of types string:int.
2. Iteratethrough your array at the last index, and then check if it exists in your array you made.
3. If it exists, inremement the int to int+1.
4. If it does not exist, add it and add int=1

Comment: *Create a new multidimensional array of types string:int* How would you know how big to make this array?  Easier to use a Map I think

Comment: True, though, by creating the function yourself you can learn the logic yourself in addition to perhaps expanding using more simpler means. But agreed there are lots of ways.